# How to get the scale factor of getPerspectiveTransform in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have image A and i want to get the bird-eye's view of image A. So I used getPerspectiveTransform method to get the transform matrix. The output result is 3x3 matrix. See my code. In my case i want to know the scale factor of the 3x3 matrix. I have looked the opencv document, but i cannot find detail of the transform matrix and i don't know how to get the scale. Also i have read some paper, the paper said we can get scaling, shearing and ratotion from a11, a12, a21, a22. See the pic. So how can i get the scale factor. Can you give me some advice? And can you explain the getPerspectiveTransform output matrix?Thank you!

```
Points[0] = Point2f(..., ...);
Points[1] = Point2f(..., ...);
Points[2] = Point2f(..., ...);
Points[3] = Point2f(..., ...);

dst[0] = Point2f(..., ...);
dst[1] = Point2f(..., ...);
dst[2] = Point2f(..., ...);
dst[3] = Point2f(..., ...);
Mat trans = getPerspectiveTransform(gpsPoints, dst);//I want to know the scale of trans
warpPerspective(A, B, trans, img.size());
```

[image]

[image]

When i change the camara position, the trapezium size and position will change. Now we set it into a rectangle and rectangle width/height was known. But i think camera in different height the rectangle size should have been changed.Because if we set into same size rectangle, the rectangle may have different detal. That's why i want to know scale from 3x3 transfrom matrix. For example, trapezium1 and trapezium2 have transfrom scale s1 and s2. So we can set  rectangle1(width,height) = s2/s1 * rectangle2(width,height).

Comment: read about homography decomposition. I'm not sure whether it's solvable at all. As you've read, scaling, rotation and shear use overlapping parts of the matrix.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with projective geometry.  You might find the [Direct Linear Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation) useful if I'm not totally in the dark about the scale. :)

Comment: I remember something... If you just use a11 a12 a21 a22 as a 2x2 homography, maybe you can decompose that matrix by using a QR decomposition. Since Q is an orthogonal matrix, it should be the rotation part of your 3x3 homography. So you can go on with the R matrix, which is upper triangle matrix holding scaleX, scaleY and shear parameters.

Comment: but this would probably only work for affine homographies without perspective elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here you go:

```
H is the homography
H = T*R*S*L with
T = [1,0,tx; 0,1,ty; 0,0,1]
R = [cos(a),sin(a),0; -sin(a),cos(a),0; 0,0,1]
S = [sx,shear,0; 0,sy,0; 0,0,1]
L = [1,0,0; 0,1,0; lx,ly,1]

where tx/ty is translation; a is rotation angle; sx/sy is scale; shear is shearing factor; lx/ly are perspective foreshortening parameters.
```

You want to compute sx and sy if I understood right.
Now If lx and ly are both 0 it would be easy to compute sx and sy. It would be to decompose the upper left part of H by QR decomposition resulting in Q*R where Q is an orthogonal matrix (= rotation matrix) and R is an upper triangle matrix (`[sx, shear; 0,sy]`).

```
h1 h2 h3
h4 h5 h6
0  0  1

=> Q*R = [h1,h2; h4,h5]
```

But lx and ly destroy the easy way. So you have to find out how the upper left part of the matrix would look like without the influence of lx and ly.

If your whole homography is:

```
h1 h2 h3
h4 h5 h6
h7 h8 1
```

then you'll have:

```
Q*R = 
h1-(h7*h3)   h2-(h8*h3)
h4-(h7*h6)   h5-(h8*h6)
```

So if you compute Q and R from this matrix, you can compute rotation, scale and shear easily.

I've tested this with a small C++ program:

```
double scaleX = (rand()%200) / 100.0;
double scaleY = (rand()%200) / 100.0;
double shear = (rand()%100) / 100.0;
double rotation = CV_PI*(rand()%360)/180.0;
double transX = rand()%100 - 50;
double transY = rand()%100 - 50;

double perspectiveX = (rand()%100) / 1000.0;
double perspectiveY = (rand()%100) / 1000.0;

std::cout << "scale: " << "(" << scaleX << "," << scaleY << ")" << "\n";
std::cout << "shear: " << shear << "\n";
std::cout << "rotation: " << rotation*180/CV_PI << " degrees" << "\n";
std::cout << "translation: " << "(" << transX << "," << transY << ")" << std::endl;

cv::Mat ScaleShearMat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << scaleX, shear, 0, 0, scaleY, 0, 0, 0, 1);
cv::Mat RotationMat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << cos(rotation), sin(rotation), 0, -sin(rotation), cos(rotation), 0, 0, 0, 1);
cv::Mat TranslationMat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1, 0, transX, 0, 1, transY, 0, 0, 1);

cv::Mat PerspectiveMat = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, perspectiveX, perspectiveY, 1);

cv::Mat HomographyMatWithoutPerspective = TranslationMat * RotationMat * ScaleShearMat;

cv::Mat HomographyMat = HomographyMatWithoutPerspective * PerspectiveMat;


std::cout << "Homography:\n" << HomographyMat << std::endl;

cv::Mat DecomposedRotaScaleShear(2,2,CV_64FC1);
DecomposedRotaScaleShear.at<double>(0,0) = HomographyMat.at<double>(0,0) - (HomographyMat.at<double>(2,0)*HomographyMat.at<double>(0,2));
DecomposedRotaScaleShear.at<double>(0,1) = HomographyMat.at<double>(0,1) - (HomographyMat.at<double>(2,1)*HomographyMat.at<double>(0,2));
DecomposedRotaScaleShear.at<double>(1,0) = HomographyMat.at<double>(1,0) - (HomographyMat.at<double>(2,0)*HomographyMat.at<double>(1,2));
DecomposedRotaScaleShear.at<double>(1,1) = HomographyMat.at<double>(1,1) - (HomographyMat.at<double>(2,1)*HomographyMat.at<double>(1,2));

std::cout << "Decomposed submat: \n" << DecomposedRotaScaleShear << std::endl;
```

Now you can test the result by using the QR matrix decomposition of http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/

First you can try to set perspectiveX and perspectiveY to zero. You'll see that you can use the upper left part of the matrix to decompose to the input values of rotation angle, shear and scale.
But if you don't set perspectiveX and perspectiveX to zero, you can use the "DecomposedRotaScaleShear" and decompose it to QR.

You'll get a result page with

```
Q:

 a a
-a a
```

here you can compute `acos(a)` to get the angle

```
R:

sx shear
0  sy
```

here you can read sx and sy directly.

Hope this helps and I hope there is no error ;)

Comment: Thank you very much!I have learned a lot from your comment.I also ask the question here,http://answers.opencv.org/question/80040/how-to-get-the-scale-factor-of-getperspectivetransform-in-opencv/ Someone said said"different parts of the image have different scale factors".I don't get the meaning.But you said scale is sx/sy,so in your answer different parts have same scale,right? Also, i wonder is my idea right or not now.  I want to get scale beacuse i don't want to set different scale into same scale.Detail see my upadate.Can you give me advice?

Comment: The term 'scale' is ambiguous. If you want to know the scale factor of the homography (for example to reject homographies with "illegal" parameters), sx qnd sy is what you need. If you want to know the pixel size/area of a specific transforned object/area you should just transform it and compute it for that specific case. What do you want to achieve? can give a concrete example what you want to compute?

Comment: I dont understand your task. You've images with the trapezoids on the left and you know the real rectangle size on the right? Or do you want to compute/approximate the real rectangle size on the right? Please create an example to show what is given and what you want to compute!

Comment: Yes, i know the rectangle ratio of  height:width(2:3) in the image.The problem is that i want to set the rectangle  size based on the transform matrix scale. You can see left side, there are two trapezoids.One is big and one is small, If i convert them into the right side rectangle. The big one is ok, but small one..you can see it have almost 10 times enlarge. I think is not good. It should convert into a small size rectangle. So i want to use scale to do this.

Comment: is the homography computed from left side to right side, or from left side to left side? It's still not clear to me.What do you mean by "i want to set the rectangle size"? What do you mean by "convert them into the right side triangle"? If you mean to warp the images, why is warping from small a problem?

Comment: I use getPerspectiveTransform(trapezoids1, rectangle),from left to right. Here are two sample,trapezoids1 to rectangle and trapezoids2 to rectangle.The rectangle is  the bird-eye's view. You know we can change the rectangle length but keep height:width(2:3). The result also is  bird-eye's view.My problem is the small warp into 10 times large rectange,  it should resize image  to high resolutions and may lose pixels.So i think we should resize the rectangle first, then warp the trapezoids to the small size rectangle. To resize the rectangle, i need to get the scale first.This is my thought.

Comment: Can you get my meaning?

Comment: Maybe... just compute the contour area of your trapezoid and the area of your rectangle with cv::contourArea and compare both (e.g. rectArea/contourArea = area scale factor)

Comment: Just using the area? Is it better than using the matrix scale? What's the different between two method? Sorry for about too many questions. Can you give me advice?

Comment: really depends on your task. matrix scale doesnt include the shear and perspective parameters so it doesnt tell you how your actual object will look like