# How to create a 2D perspective transform matrix from individual components?

Tags: opencv, transformation, perspective, affinetransform

I am trying to create a 2D perspective transform matrix from individual components like translation, rotation, scale, shear. But at the end the matrix is not producing a true perspective effect like the image below. I think I am missing some component in the code that I wrote to create the matrix. Could some one help me add the missing components and their formulation in the below function? I have used opencv library for my code

[image]

```
cv::Mat getPerspMatrix2D( double rz, double s, double tx, double ty ,double shx, double shy)
{

cv::Mat R = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) <<
        cos(rz), -sin(rz), 0,
        sin(rz), cos(rz), 0,
        0, 0, 1);

cv::Mat S = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) <<
        s, 0, 0,
        0, s, 0,
        0, 0, 1);


cv::Mat Sh = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) <<
        1, shx, 0,
        shy, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 1);


cv::Mat T = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) <<
        1, 0, tx,
        0, 1, ty,
        0, 0, 1);

return T * Sh * S * R;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html

Comment: This link shows how to derive perspective transform from point pairs. I would like to manipulate different components of a perspective transform. Currently I have rotation, translation, scale, shear as the transform components. Is there any other component responsible for perspective transform?

Answer (score 8):

Keywords are **Homography** and **8DOF**. Taken from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389125/how-to-get-the-scale-factor-of-getperspectivetransform-in-opencv) and [2](http://docdingle.com/teaching/cs545/presents/p12b_cs545_WarpsP2.pdf) there exists two coefficients for perspective transformation.  But it needs a 2nd step to calculate it. I'm not familiar with OpenCV but I'm hoping to answer your question a bit late in a basically way ;-)

### Step 1

You can imagine lx describes a vanishing point on the x axis. The image shows a31=lx=1. lx=100 is less transformation. For lx=0 the position is infinite far means no perspective transform = identity matrix.

```
     [1  0  0] 
PL = [0  1  0] 
     [lx ly 1]

lx/ly are perspective foreshortening parameters
```

[image]

### Step 2

When you apply a right hand matrix multiplication P x [u; v; 1] you will recognize that the last value in the result is sometimes other than 1. For affine transformation it is always 1 for perspective projection not. In the 2nd step the result is scaled to make the last coefficient 1. This is a part of the effect.

[image]

### Your Example Image

```
 Image' = P4 x P3 x P2 x P1 x Image
```

1. I would translate the center of the blue rectangle to the origin `tx=-w/2` and `ty=-h/2` = P1.
2. Apply projective projection with `ly = h` (to make both sides at an angle)
3. Eventually translate back that all point are located in one quadrant
4. Eventually scale to desired size

Step 2 from the perspective projection can be done after 2.) or at the end.